# Image swapping hyperlinks

Tags: javascript

I want to have some hyperlink images that keep changing after a period of time..I have used 2 arrays images and links..2 respective functions execute that change image and links respectively after 2 seconds of time..But I am getting a blank screen as output..I wrote the code as:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
 </head>
<body>
<img id="img"  width="1300" height="200"/>
<link id="link" >
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=0;
var y=0;
var images = new Array();
var links = new Array();
images[0] = "D:\images\31.jpg";
images[1] = "D:\images\32.jpg";

links[0] = "https://www.google.co.in" ;
links[1] = "https://www.facebook.com" ;

 function changeImage()
 {
document.getElementById("img").src=images[x];
x = (x + 1) % images.length;
}
 function changeLinks()
 { 
document.getElementById("link").href=links[y];
y = (y + 1) % links.length;
}
 window.onload = function() {
  changeImage();
  setInterval(changeImage,2000);
  }
window.onload = function() {
  changeLinks();
  setInterval(changeLinks,2000);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
images[0] = "D:\images\31.jpg";
images[1] = "D:\images\32.jpg";
```

those are supposed to be hyperlinks, not file paths! Also, the backslash is an escape char in JS, so you need to double it (\\). So try something like:

```
images[0] = "file:/D:/images/31.jpg";
images[1] = "file:/D:/images/32.jpg";
```

Comment: can u plz elaborate..what does the file in ur code line represent?..and where to give "\\"?

Comment: Have a look at this for more on escaping characters in Javascript : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp Basic string escape in JS!

Comment: Better copy/move the images into the server path and use relative paths like `../images/31.jpg`. Using a file url and point to the disk is really not the best option.

Comment: And you don't need to use the \\ since in the url the normal slash is used, however my point is about the fact that in `...images\31.jpg`, the `\31` would be treated as a string escape rather than characters backslash followed by 3 followed by 1.

Comment: should i rename the image name?

Comment: Try to place your images in the same directory as your html, and then write `images[0] = ".\\31.jpg";` respectively. By the way, the `link` element is misused. It should be `a`.